# How to force rpm and yum to fail if a GPG signature is missing or cannot otherwise be verified?

Tags: centos, rhel, security, yum, rpm

How can I force `rpm` and `yum` to fail if a GPG signature is missing from a package or otherwise cannot be verified due to a missing key? For the example below, assume the RPM has been signed but the key has not been installed.

With RPM I see a warning, but I would like this to fail so that I am forced to manually install the signing key.

```
# rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{name}-%{version}-%{release} --> %{summary}\n'
gpg-pubkey-c105b9de-4e0fd3a3 --> gpg(CentOS-6 Key (CentOS 6 Official Signing Key) <centos-6-key@centos.org>)

# rpm -ivh http://yum.example.com/company-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://yum.example.com/company-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.3VmFk2: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 3bd6ec30: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    1:company-release     ########################################### [100%]
```

With yum, I see no warnings related to the fact that the signing key is not installed.

```
# yum install -vy http://yum.example.com/company-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
```

Are there additional flags I can pass to these commands or a configuration setting I can modify to change the behavior? Or must I download the RPM and run `rpm --checksig` prior to installation?

Answer (score 4):

The main point to understand about GPG checking for packages is that the GPG signature is embedded within the package, and the GPG keys are stored in the rpmdb. There is no secure API to ask "What key is package X signed with" you can only ask "Is package X signed with a key in the rpmdb" and "Does key Y exist in the rpmdb". Also note that this means that a package can only be signed by one key, and that changing the signature changes the packages.

Yum performs a number of steps when it downloads a package from a repository configured with "gpgcheck = 1" (the default).

1. After the first package from a repository is downloaded, a simple
   "is this package signed with a known gpgkey" call is done. If it is,
   nothing is done. If it isn't a warning is displayed to the user.
   This is purely informational.
2. Before the transaction starts yum checks that the package is signed
       with a known gpgkey (one already installed in the rpmdb), if it is
       the package is valid and no other steps are performed. If not then
       it continues to #3.
3. Yum downloads all the files given in the "gpgkey" data for the
       repository that the package comes from. Yum parses that, ignoring
       any keys already present in the rpmdb. If there are no new keys, yum
       will fail.
4. If there is a "gpgcakey" specified for the repository, then yum
       will download all the files given in the "gpgcakey" data. Yum parses
       that, ignoring any keys already present in that repositories gpg
       keyring. If there are no gpgcakeys installed after parsing the file,
       yum will fail. If there are new gpgcakeys, then if they are already
       imported as CA keys for another repo. they are automatically
       imported. If this is the first tiem we've seen this CA key the user
       is asked if he wants to install the key (unless -y is given). If he
       says no to *any* key, yum fails (although all imported keys stay in
       the repo. gpg keyring).
5. If there is at least one valid "gpgcakey", yum will try to download
       a "gpgkey".asc file. If that doesn't exists, yum moves on to step #6
       as though there was no gpgcakey. If it does exist then the "gpgkey"
       is tested against the "gpgcakey" and if it passes it's added to the
       rpmdb, if it fails then yum fails (although all imported keys stay
       in the rpmdb).
6. If there are new gpgkeys, then the user is asked if he wants to
       install each key (unless -y is given). If he says no to *any* key,
       yum fails.
7. After installing any new keys, yum again checks the package
       signature against the gpgkeys in the rpmdb. If this fails, yum
       fails.

Answer (score 3):

Put `localpkg_gpgcheck=1` in /etc/yum.conf and ensure you always yum to install rpms.

If you have an rpm on the local files system just do

```
yum install <rpm-on-local-filesys>
```

Make sure you also set these in all the repos in /etc/yum.repos.d

```
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/SOME-APPROVED-GPG-KEY
```

As you mentioned, the best you'll get out of installing via rpm is a warning and there is no means to configure it to refuse to install on a non-present GPG key.